# Unity heal over time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just implemented a heal overtime to my unity project and I was wondering how do I stop the heal overtime while the player in in range of the enemy.. and then start the heal overtime when the player is out of range of the enemy? I tried using a bool and it didn't work.. I also tried using StopCoroutine what also didn't work

Here is my code:

```
private void Awake()
{
    if (currentHealth < 100)
    {
        StartCoroutine(HealCo());
    }
 
    healDuration = new WaitForSeconds(2f);
}

private void Update()
{
    healthbar.value = currentHealth;
   
    if (currentHealth > maxHealth)
    {
        currentHealth = 100;
    }
}    

private IEnumerator HealCo()
{
    currentHealth += healAmount;
    yield return healDuration;
    StartCoroutine(HealCo());
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Generally we only need to see your [mcve] rather than other elements making up your game.  Good luck!

Comment: Where is the code that does the damage? Can you post it?

Comment: I posted a comment with it.

Comment: There are a number of ways. A simple way would be to determine you are in fight. If in fight skip all the code in the coroutine

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use the [enabled flag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour-enabled.html) that all MonoBehaviours already have.

```
private void OnEnable()
{
    StartCoroutine(HealingLoop());
}

public void SetHealth(float value)
{
    currentHealth = Mathf.Clamp(value, 0f, 100f);
    healthbar.value = currentHealth;
}

private IEnumerator HealingLoop()
{
    while(enabled)
    {
        yield return healDuration;
        SetHealth(currentHealth + healAmount)
    }
}
```

This relies on HealingLoop coming to an end when the enabled property is set to false, and the OnEnable event function starting it running again when the enabled property is set back to enabled.

**UPDATE:**
You can set the state of the enabled property based on whether or not enemies are currently in range of the player by creating another component that invokes a [UnityEvent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html) whenever enemies come within the range or leave the range.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class EnemyInRangeChangedEventTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private bool invertReactionArgument;

    [SerializeField]
    private UnityEvent<bool> reaction;

    private bool enemyInRangeLastFrame;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        bool enemyInRangeNow = IsEnemyInRange();
        InvokeReaction(enemyInRangeNow);
        enemyInRangeLastFrame = enemyInRangeNow;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        bool enemyInRangeNow = IsEnemyInRange();
        if(enemyInRangeNow != enemyInRangeLastFrame)
        {
            InvokeReaction(enemyInRangeNow);
            enemyInRangeLastFrame = enemyInRangeNow;
        }
    }
    
    private bool IsEnemyInRange() => enemyMovement.chase;
    private void InvokeReaction(bool enemyInRangeNow) => reaction.Invoke(invertReactionArgument ? !enemyInRangeNow : enemyInRangeNow);
}
```

Then you can connect this event to the enabled property using the Inspector.

[image]

Comment: HealingLoop should have return type IEnumerator

Comment: True, my mistake! I'll update the code.

Comment: Hey I really appreciate your comment.. but I didn't completely understand what you meant.. the healing part works perfectly but I don't know how to stop the healing loop when the enemy starts chasing the player.. I tried adding a bool to the enemy chase but couldn't get it to work.. here is my code : private void Update() { if (enemyMovement.chase == true) { StopCoroutine("HealingLoop"); } } –

Comment: To stop the healing set `healing.enabled = false;`, with `healing` being a reference to the component containing the HealingLoop.

One way to do this would be using another component that invokes a [UnityEvent<bool>](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html) whenever the state of enemies being in range changes, and hooking this to control the state of the enabled property.

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example of how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a coroutine if you are using Update() method. It really depends on the architecture and what you exactly need, but the easiest way for me will be to create the method Heal() and check in Update() if it should be invoked. That can be done using bool isHealing which value can be set whatever you want.

If you want to heal exact value of HP or time then calculate everything in update like (timeHealing - Time.deltaTime) etc