# Heal reset Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I implemented healing into my Unity project and have a timer for when the player can heal and I want the timer to reset every time the player takes damage but I can't seem to get it to work.. here is my code:

```
private void HealthRegen()
{
    timer += Time.deltaTime;
   
    if (timer > timeToHeal) 
    {
        StartCoroutine(HealthRegenCo());
    }
    if (damaged == true)
    {
        timer = 0f;
    }
}

private void SetHealth(float value)
{
    currentHealth = Mathf.Clamp(value, 0f, 100f);
    healthbar.value = currentHealth;
}

private IEnumerator HealthRegenCo()
{
    while (enabled)
    {
       yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
       SetHealth(currentHealth + healAmount);
       Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: HealthRegenCo() <-- can you post that ?

Comment: who called HealthRegen() ? in Update() ?

Comment: How is this different from your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73264870/unity-heal-over-time) asked yesterday?  Or at least apply from what was learnt yesterday?

Comment: I couldn't get any of the methods from yesterday to work :/

Answer (score 0):

I see what happened here, let me descriptively explain what your code does.

I assume that `HealthReign()` is called in `Update()`, and the timer is increasing. When the timer goes above `timeToHeal`, the coroutine is started. If `damage` is set to `true`, `timer` is set to `0`. When the `timer` goes above `timeToHeal`, the code inside `else if` block doesn't get called at all due to it being an `else if`. Code inside `else if` is only read when the condition in the `if` statement is `false`.

Fix, don't use `else if`, just use another `if`

```cs
private void HealthRegen()
{
    timer += Time.deltaTime;
   
    if (timer > timeToHeal) 
    {
        StartCoroutine(HealthRegenCo());
    }
    
    if (damaged == true)
    {
        timer = 0f;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not called in Update() that would be bad for performance also if I did that then the player would be healed every frame

Comment: @MitchellBisset but Time.deltaTime <-- this is working by Update()

Answer (score 0):

Time.deltaTime  <-- this is working by Update() , so you can count time by your coroutine. like this.

```
private void HealthRegen()
{
    StartCoroutine(HealthRegenCo());
}

private void SetHealth(float value)
{
    currentHealth = Mathf.Clamp(value, 0f, 100f);
    healthbar.value = currentHealth;
}

private IEnumerator HealthRegenCo()
{
    while (enabled)
    {
       yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
       timer += 0.1f;
       SetHealth(currentHealth + healAmount);
       Save();
       if(timer > timeToHeal)
       {
            yield break;
       }
    }
}
```

//------------------------ I saw your question yestday , so I think like this is simply , and you can use "HealthOpen" to open or close health.

```
float time = 0;
public bool HealthOpen = false;

private void Update()
{
    if(HealthOpen)
    {
        time += Time.detlaTime;
        if(time > 0.1f)
        {
            time = 0;
            setHeal(currentheal + heal);
        }
        if(currentheal >= 100)
        {
            HealthOpen = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your comment.. but sadly now the healing stops completely

Comment: Do you called StartCoroutine(HealthRegenCo()) <-- this line? @MitchellBisset

Comment: That gets called in HealthRegen and HealthRegen gets called whenever the player takes damage.

Comment: what damage ? is this for health? why take damage and you need to health ?

Comment: Your method stops the healing when the player takes damage which is great.. but the healing doesn't start once the player hasn't taken damage

Comment: Actually I think it was my StopCoroutine(healSetter); what was stopping it